# Powershell: extract mediaid from string

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I want to extract `mediaid` from the string

```
"\u003cimage mediaid=\"{2EB3AFF5-24C6-4C1F-8957-37CBFCBED751}\" alt=\"Caulfield to Dandenong Level Crossing Removal\" height=\"\" width=\"\" hspace=\"\" vspace=\"\" /\u003e",
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Why did you tag this with all PowerShell versions? What version are you **actually** using?

Comment: @Theo I am using ver 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the lack of requirements in the posted question, some sort of regex may be required:

To extract `mediaid` in this case or any identifier name coming before a quoted GUID, you may do the following:

```
$str = '"\u003cimage mediaid=\"{2EB3AFF5-24C6-4C1F-8957-37CBFCBED751}\" alt=\"Caulfield to Dandenong Level Crossing Removal\" height=\"\" width=\"\" hspace=\"\" vspace=\"\" /\u003e",'
$regex = [regex]'\S+(?==\\"{[-A-F0-9]+}\\")'
$regex.Match($str).Value
```

To extract the value of `mediaid`, you may do the following:

```
$str = '"\u003cimage mediaid=\"{2EB3AFF5-24C6-4C1F-8957-37CBFCBED751}\" alt=\"Caulfield to Dandenong Level Crossing Removal\" height=\"\" width=\"\" hspace=\"\" vspace=\"\" /\u003e",'
$regex = [regex]'(?<=mediaid=)\S+'
$regex.Match($str).Value
```

**Explanation:**

- `\S+`: Matches non-whitespace character one or more times (`+`)
- `(?=<something>)`: Positive lookahead for `<something>` but doesn't capture the characters
- (?<=)`: Positive lookbehind for` ` but doesn't capture
- `[A-F0-9-]`: Character class match that includes uppercase `A` through `F`, zero through nine, and `-` (dash). Note that uppercase is enforced here because we are using the .NET class `Regex`. Typically, Windows PowerShell is case insensitive without specifying otherwise, e.g. `$str -match '[A-F]'` would match `a-f` or `A-F`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Substring` function. Syntax is: `.Substring( StartIndex [, length] )`

```
$string= '\u003cimage mediaid=\"{2EB3AFF5-24C6-4C1F-8957-37CBFCBED751}\" alt=\"Caulfield to Dandenong Level Crossing Removal\" height=\"\" width=\"\" hspace=\"\" vspace=\"\" /\u003e'
$mediaid = $string.Substring($string.Length - 148, 36)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use regular expressions:

```
$text = '"\u003cimage mediaid=\"{2EB3AFF5-24C6-4C1F-8957-37CBFCBED751}\" alt=\"Caulfield to Dandenong Level Crossing Removal\" height=\"\" width=\"\" hspace=\"\" vspace=\"\" /\u003e"'

[Regex]::Match($text, '(?<={).*(?=})').Value
```

Which returns:

`2EB3AFF5-24C6-4C1F-8957-37CBFCBED751`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the regex `-replace` operator to do this, where you simply capture what you want to keep and remove all the rest:

```
$string= '\u003cimage mediaid=\"{2EB3AFF5-24C6-4C1F-8957-37CBFCBED751}\" alt=\"Caulfield to Dandenong Level Crossing Removal\" height=\"\" width=\"\" hspace=\"\" vspace=\"\" /\u003e'
$string -replace '.*mediaid=\\?"({[0-9A-F-]+}).*', '$1'
```

Result:

```
{2EB3AFF5-24C6-4C1F-8957-37CBFCBED751}
```

Regex details:

```
.                    Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                 Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
mediaid=             Match the characters “mediaid=” literally
\\                   Match the character “\” literally
   ?                 Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"                    Match the character “"” literally
(                    Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   {                 Match the character “{” literally
   [0-9A-F-]         Match a single character present in the list below
                     A character in the range between “0” and “9”
                     A character in the range between “A” and “F”
                     The character “-”
      +              Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   }                 Match the character “}” literally
)
.                    Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *                 Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```